# HTML CSS hide overflowing parts of image

Tags: html, css

I am new to Web Development.
And I am having a problem. This is the image i am talking about:

[image]

How do i set whatever part of the image outside of the div to invisible?
Or should i crop the picture

Here is a copy of the code

```
<div style="height:200px; width:200px; border-radius:100px; border:2px solid blue;text-align:center;"> 
<img src="../pics/2.jpg" style="height:180px;">
</div>
```

Comment: it would be worth learning about how to include css files for your styles, using styles on html elements like that will cause problems in the future

Comment: This is a small part of my code, where i am experimenting a new idea of mine, i didn't think it worth it to create a separate CSS file for them. Thanks for the advice however @Toni Leigh

Comment: np, just when you said 'i am new to web dev' :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting `overflow:hidden` into the `div`'s styling, as shown:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; height:200px; width:200px; border-radius:100px; border:2px solid blue;text-align:center;"> 
   <img src="../pics/2.jpg" style="height:180px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `overflow: hidden` to the parent `<div>`